# DotNetNuke create new portal didnt create new portal

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've installed dotnetnuke today for the first time, I've created a new portal via host/portals. It says its created it but just doesn't find it. I just don't know how/why?

The portal ID is 4. and there is a directory in dotnetnuke/Portals/4

But the url localhost/bmd (name of the portal) doesn't resolve to anything/

Anyone know a solution to this? maybe it happened to you too?

Cheers

Comment: I assume it was a child portal and not a parent?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have a "localhost/bmd" in your PortalAlias table

Comment: Yup its definately in there. when i get the 404 error page its looking for a folder bmd in the wwwroot directory but it doesn't exist. I'm guessing it should have been made by the application?